# How to pass two values from two relates tables to another page using anchor tag

Tags: php, anchor

I have two tables which are Order Table and Seller Table that looks something like this

[image]

I tried to `LEFT JOIN` the two tables so I can get the details of the seller in the `Order Table`.

I have a problem now, how can i pass the value of `seller_id` and also the `order_date` from the order table according to the selected values. I want to pass the two values to the `report-summary.php` using anchor tag.
For example if I select seller `Mark` it will fetch the `seller_id=1`and `month= 2021-03`( this is the date from order table). How can i achieve this?

It would be better if you guys can show me examples of code on how to solve this. Thank you so much in advance any help will be appreciated!

I tried the codes below all i get is empty values. where the URL shows:

`http://localhost/myfile/admin/report-summary.php?sid=&month=`

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto">
                    <input type="month" id="month" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('Y-m'); ?>">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto">
                    <select class="form-control" id="seller">
                      <option value="">Select All</option>
                      <?php
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM seller ORDER BY seller_register";

                      $query = $conn->query($sql);
                      while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                       
                      ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['seller_name'];?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="loadreport();">
                      <i class="nc-icon nc-zoom-split"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <?php
                      $sql="SELECT * FROM order LEFT JOIN seller ON ordert.seller_id = sellert.id ORDER BY seller_register";
                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
                    $seller_id= $row['seller_id'];
                    $month= date('Y-m');

                    if(isset($_POST['seller'])) {
                      $seller_id = $_POST['seller_id'];
                      $month = date('Y-m');
                    }
                    else{
                      $seller_id = '';
                      $month ='';
                    }
                      echo '
                      <a href="report-summary.php?sid='.$seller_id.'&month='.$month.'">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="height: 34px;">
                          <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> &nbsp;Export to Excel 
                        </button>
                      </a>';
                    
                      ?>
```

Comment: You overwrite $seller_id  and $month variables in the  if(isset($_POST['seller'])) conditional statement. Revise its logic or remove it completely.

Comment: @Shadow how do i pass the values then if i remove it completely? Thanks

Comment: You are passing (printing out) the values just fine. However, you are overwriting the values you read from the database in that if block.

Comment: @Shadow but how can i pass the values without the if statement? Can you explain in details on how should i pass the two values? Thanks